# Large number of head gasket questions

Tags: discussion

There are a ton of HG questions that are open. There are a few common model or brand specific cases (disappearing coolant on the Hondas). Maybe we could pick a few old questions, one for each standard symptom, and start paring down these questions to our "one true answer"?

We could pick standard symptoms:
Oil in coolant
White smoke from exhaust
No start condition with working ignition

Then start closing newer questions as duplicates.

Comment: I think your too quick to close some questions rather than try to help the troubleshoot the issue with the OP.  These aren't questions where pasting some code into the answer makes it better.  These are troubleshooting events and some of the people don't know what they are doing and need guidance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are seeing there are dulpicates in these questions, by all mean pare them down. Select one, in your opinion, which answers the question and put the other ones as duplicates. The process of closing a question involves several people to review the action, so it shouldn't be an issue. Only kids have the ability to throw the close hammer at it and make it stick on the first go around.

If the questions are different (different circumstances, but same outcome), it is my opinion these should be left open. To me this could help others who have a similar question get to the end result and hopefully not ask a question which will get closed.

If, on the other hand, you are suggesting we should just point these question towards the main question through a comment or something to that effect, I don't think there is any issue there, either.

One of the issues which happens on the site is people with no mechanical understanding ask questions. Because they have no typical understanding, they aren't asking with the right terms and therefore the other questions don't pop up to them as a possible answer. This is just one of those things we have to deal with.

Comment: I think the OP's should be helped more. Just closing questions doesn't do any good for the site and doesn't help retain users.

Answer (score 1):

**Attempting to put together some questions and answers**

I agree with you that the head gasket questions become a little redundant.  I think the real challenge is assisting the OP with troubleshooting rather than just closing the question as a dupe, which does nothing for the OP who may or may not know what to do to identify that is really the issue other than some faceless verbiage telling them that, "it's a head gasket"

I've been trying to ask some questions regarding troubleshooting in order to give the OP some links and background on how they can validate that the issue is what we say it is.

Here's a couple of examples of some that I think can begin to build a body of links and data that an OP can consume.

- [How do I troubleshoot the source of oil in my coolant?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/how-do-i-troubleshoot-the-source-of-oil-in-my-coolant)
- [What is a leak down tester and what can I do with it?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26384/what-is-a-leak-down-tester-and-what-can-i-do-with-it)
- [What exactly is a head gasket?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/24683/what-exactly-is-a-head-gasket)
- [How to test if head gaskets are blown?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/17378/how-to-test-if-head-gaskets-are-blown)
- [How do I troubleshoot the source of oil in my coolant?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/26363/how-do-i-troubleshoot-the-source-of-oil-in-my-coolant/26744#26744)

I'm going to create some meta posts as a follow up with various links in categories so responders can find them easily and include links to resources to help them to identify the issue as well understand it a bit more.